# Error when use react-chartjs-2 to create a Doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a bmi calculator app. Input are Weight and Height , output is bmi.
Everything is ok, but when i change result with display chart it has error `"arc" is not a registered element.`

I used react-chartjs-2 version 4.3.1, and also import it in code

```
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2';

const chartData = {
    labels: ['Underweight', 'Normal', 'Overweight'],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [
          bmi < 18.5 ? 1 : 0,
          bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25 ? 1 : 0,
          bmi >= 25 ? 1 : 0,
        ],
        backgroundColor: ['#32cd32', '#007bff', '#ff6347'],
      },
    ],
  };

<Doughnut data={chartData} />
```

So how can i fix it?